# Getting this weird error when trying to run DVC pull

Tags: dvc

I am new to using DVC and just exploring it. I am trying to pull data from s3 that was pushed by another person on my team. But I am getting this error:

```
WARNING: Some of the cache files do not exist neither locally nor on remote. Missing cache files:
name: head_test_file.csv, md5: 45db668193ba44228d61115b1d0304fe
WARNING: Cache '45db668193ba44228d61115b1d0304fe' not found. File 'head_test_file.csv' won't be created.
No changes.
ERROR: failed to pull data from the cloud - Checkout failed for following targets:
head_test_file.csv
Did you forget to fetch?
```

Comment: FYI: one may try `pip install dvc[gs]` instead of `pip install dvc`.

Answer (score 5):

My mistake. I ran `dvc add` but I had missed to run `dvc push`. Running this fixed it.

When I ran `dvc add` it did `create my_file.csv.dvc` file but it was not pushed. Hence when I was trying to pull it saw the .dvc file but got confused.

It was a simple solution, but it took a while for me to figure out. Since this is a new tool, asking and answering my own question just in case if someone else makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to run [`dvc install`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/install) which installs a Git hook to automate `dvc push` before `git push` (:

> Push: While publishing changes to the Git remote with git push, its easy to forget that the dvc push command is necessary to upload new or updated data files and directories tracked by DVC to remote storage.
>
> This hook automates dvc push.

Comment: I think you mean `dvc push` after `dvc add` right?

Comment: Nope. See https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/install#installed-git-hooks